# PHP Get selected Values on a drop down list

Tags: php

I have this script that displays the year, month and day on a drop down.

my question is: how do I get the selected values in the format of d-m-y?

let's say if i will have a button to get the current selected values and display on a textbox. how would i do it?

any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<html>
    <body>
<?php
    $months = array(
            'January', 
            'February', 
            'March', 
            'April', 
            'May', 
            'June',
            'July', 
            'August', 
            'September', 
            'October', 
            'November',
            'December'
        );
    $weekday = array(
            'Sunday',
            'Monday',
            'Tuesday',
            'Wednesday',
            'Thursday',
            'Friday',
            'Saturday'
        );
    $days = range(1,31);
    $years = range (2010, 2020);

    $currentDay = date('d');
    $currentMonth = date('F');
    $currentYear = date('Y');

    echo "<select name='weekday'>";
    foreach($days as $valued) {

        if($valued == $currentDay)
        { 
            $default = 'selected="selected"'; 
            echo '<option '.$default.' value="'.$valued.'">'.$valued.'</option>\n';
        } else {
            $default='';
            echo '<option '.$default.' value="'.$valued.'">'.$valued.'</option>\n';
        }
        } 
    echo '</select>&nbsp;';
        echo "<select name='month'>";
        foreach($months as $valuem) {
            if($valuem==$currentMonth)
        { 
            $default1 = 'selected="selected"';
            echo '<option '.$default1.' value="'.$valuem.'">'.$valuem.'</option>\n';
        } else {
            $default1 = '';    
            echo '<option '.$default1.' value="'.$valuem.'">'.$valuem.'</option>\n';
        }

    } 
        echo '</select> &nbsp; ';
        echo "<select name='year'>";

        foreach ($years as $valuey) {

    if($valuey == $currentYear)
    { 
       $default2 = 'selected="selected"';
       echo '<option '.$default2.' value="'.$valuey.'">'.$valuey.'</option>\n';
    } else {
           $default2 = '';
           echo '<option '.$default2.' value="'.$valuey.'">'.$valuey.'</option>\n';
    }

        }  
        echo '</select> &nbsp; ';
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo $currentDay;and tell the value

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, let's say if the user changes the value. How can i put a button on the code to display it's selected values? thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $message=$_POST['weekday'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['year'];
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$months = array(
        'January', 
        'February', 
        'March', 
        'April', 
        'May', 
        'June',
        'July', 
        'August', 
        'September', 
        'October', 
        'November',
        'December'
    );
$weekday = array(
        'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday'
    );
$days = range(1,31);
$years = range (2010, 2020);

$currentDay = date('d');
$currentMonth = date('F');
$currentYear = date('Y');
echo '<form method="post" action="">';
echo "<select name='weekday'>";
foreach($days as $valued) {

    if($valued == $currentDay)
    { 
        $default = 'selected="selected"'; 
        echo '<option '.$default.' value="'.$valued.'">'.$valued.'</option>\n';
    } else {
        $default='';
        echo '<option '.$default.' value="'.$valued.'">'.$valued.'</option>\n';
    }
    } 
echo '</select>&nbsp;';
    echo "<select name='month'>";
    foreach($months as $valuem) {
        if($valuem==$currentMonth)
    { 
        $default1 = 'selected="selected"';
        echo '<option '.$default1.' value="'.$valuem.'">'.$valuem.'</option>\n';
    } else {
        $default1 = '';    
        echo '<option '.$default1.' value="'.$valuem.'">'.$valuem.'</option>\n';
    }

} 
    echo '</select> &nbsp; ';
    echo "<select name='year'>";

    foreach ($years as $valuey) {

if($valuey == $currentYear)
{ 
   $default2 = 'selected="selected"';
   echo '<option '.$default2.' value="'.$valuey.'">'.$valuey.'</option>\n';
} else {
       $default2 = '';
       echo '<option '.$default2.' value="'.$valuey.'">'.$valuey.'</option>\n';
}

    }  
    echo '</select> &nbsp; ';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Get Selected Date">          </input></form>';
?>
<p>You Select:</p>
<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($message)){echo $message;}  ?>"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let me correct you on a couple of mistakes:

1. The select named *weekday* should be named *day*. This is not mandatory, but it's good practice for the names of the selects to actually respect the meaning of the data inside.
2. If you want to submit data to the server, you **must** enclose elements like <select>, <input>, <textarea> in a form.

`<form action="#" method="POST"> [code be here] </form>`

should do.

I don't really understand what you are trying to do. However, I have narrowed it down to 2 things:

1. You are trying to get back the values to the server, for further processing. I imagine the "print the date in a textbox" is just a mock-up case. In this case, you would use the $_GET/$_POST arrays(depending on the method used by the form, see above). As such, considering the current scenario, you would have:

   ```
   $selectedDay = $_POST['weekday'];
   $selectedMonth = $_POST['month'];
   $selectedYear = $_POST['year'];
   ```

   Then, like it was said before, you would have

   ```
   <textarea><?php echo $selectedDay."-".$selectedMonth."-".$selectedYear;?></textarea>
   ```
2. (Most likely) You are trying to operate on the page without sending the values back to the server. For example, every time a user selects a different value in the select, a script runs and fills a textbox with: "You have selected 23-2-1992". In this case, you don't use PHP, but Javascript.

Here's your code, doing just that(refactored):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTextBox()
{
    day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    aux = document.getElementById("month");

    month = aux.value;
    //Use the following if you want the month number instead of the month name, e.g. 12-4-2012
    //month = aux.options[aux.selectedIndex].id;

    year = document.getElementById("year").value;

    document.getElementById("textbox").value = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
}
</script>
<title>Some title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$months = array ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June','July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November','December');
$weekday = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
$days = range(1,31);
$years = range (2010, 2020);

$currentDay = date('d');
$currentMonth = date('F');
$currentYear = date('Y');

echo "<select name='day' id='day' onChange='updateTextBox()'>";
foreach($days as $valued) {

    if($valued == $currentDay)
    { 
          $default = 'selected="selected"'; 
            echo '<option '.$default.' value="'.$valued.'">'.$valued.'</option>\n';
    } else {
          $default='';
            echo '<option '.$default.' value="'.$valued.'">'.$valued.'</option>\n';
    }

} 
echo '</select>&nbsp;';


echo "<select name='month' id='month' onChange='updateTextBox()'>";

foreach($months as $array_key=>$valuem) {

    if($valuem==$currentMonth)
    { 
        $default1 = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $default1 = '';
    }
    echo '<option '.$default1.' id="'.($array_key+1).'" value="'.$valuem.'">'.$valuem.'</option>\n';

} echo '</select> &nbsp; ';

echo "<select name='year' id='year' onChange='updateTextBox()'>";

foreach ($years as $valuey) {

        if($valuey == $currentYear)
        { 
            $default2 = 'selected="selected"';
        } else {
            $default2 = '';
        }
        echo '<option '.$default2.' value="'.$valuey.'">'.$valuey.'</option>\n';

}
echo '</select> &nbsp; ';
?>

<textarea id="textbox"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi Vlad, i want to transfer the data to the server. I was thinking if I will have the data on a textbox, I can have a button to get the data on a textbox and send to the server. (I realized i'm having a wrong concept). So if i want that code above to enclosed on a form how I do it? and how can I send the selected data? thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Do as afshin suggested. If you want the data to be automatically refreshed when a user changes a value, just add the following to each select:
onChange="document.getElementById("enclosing_form").submit()"
However, the <form element must have: id="enclosing_form" for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea>

<?php

echo $currentDay."-".$currentMonth."-".$currentYear;

?>
</textarea>
```

That would display the date in the format you requested in a textarea

Comment: thanks for your reply but when the date value changes how would I get its updated contents?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use the date.

If you are wanting PHP to make use of it - then you will need to do what 'Vlad Teodorescu' said and enclose the form elements in a form. If you are just trying to add it to the textarea at client side, then you can do this using the javascript in 'Vlad Teodorescu's suggestion. What context are you trying to use this in?